# In Android Studio 3.0.1 an Android Profiler can't find Genymotion device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

Today I updated my Android Studio from 2.1.2 to 3.0.1. After this I saw that Google introduced new tool named Android Profiler instead of Android Monitor. But it doesn't working with Genymotion devices on my PC. Note that studio sees the Genymotion device and successfully installs and compiles the application onto it.

How to connect Genymotion virtual device to Android Profiler?

[image]